# Invalidate or clip text

Tags: c, winapi

I'm trying to monitor the mouse position on client area of window. for example:

```
WM_MOUSEMOVE:
{
   std::ostringstring oss;

   xPos = LOWORD(lParam);
   yPos = HIWORD(lParam);

   oss << xPos << ", " << yPos;

   TextOut(hDC, 100, 100, oss.str().c_str(), oss.str().size());
}
```

Do i need to measure the height, width of fonts to get the area to erase before drawing out new text? I don't understand if i would need clipping to redraw the region or just invalidate rect would be enough for properly drawing the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you draw some text, use [GetTextExtentPoint32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144938(VS.85).aspx) to measure the size of the area written, and save that somewhere. Then when you try to draw something new, you can pass a rectangle based on that value into InvalidateRect to indicate your desire to erase, then UpdateWindow to make the erasure happen immediately.

Comment: Would it be possible to do the draw operation in WM_PAINT for the text to get redrawn itself? Because If I put TextOut in WM_PAINT it would only invalidate the old area written.

Comment: @cnd it's actually best practice to put the `TextOut` in WM_PAINT, because Windows will regulate the number of WM_PAINT messages you have to process. You will need to invalidate a larger rectangle to make sure the new value was displayed without being cut off, or perhaps invalidate the whole control.